# Predicting future transporation mode based on previous patterns

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, prediction

I want to **predict future transportation mode** (car,walk, bus) of a user in a trip. A trip is composed of multiple segments and each segment consists of features like speed, distance, time and transportation mode. Based on known features of previous segments (here segment 1,2,3) i want to predict the transportation mode or if possible predicting the features of next segment (segment 4) and so on for segment 5,6 etc.

**segment No -> speed -> distance -> time -> transportation mode**

segment 1 -> 70 km/h -> 30 km -> 28 min -> car

segtment 2 -> 3 km/h -> 1 km -> 15 min -> walk

segment 3 -> 40 km/h -> 10 km -> 20 min -> bus

segment 4 -> ??? -> ??? -> ??? -> ???

segment 5 -> ??? -> ??? -> ??? -> ???
.

.

.

.

.

segment n -> ??? -> ??? -> ??? -> ???

which statistical or machine learning models would be helpful to predict the future transportation modes based on existing patterns?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a dataset of **Trips**, which consists of $N$ trips, each one composed of $n_i$ segments data-pairs ($\boldsymbol{x^{(i,j)}}$, $y^{(i,j)}$), where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is your vector of features (distance, speed, time) and $y$ is your transportation mode.

Only based on the structure of your data, the obvious possibility that comes to my mind is a simple MLP to map your trip features to transportation mode ($\boldsymbol{x}^{(i,j)} \to y^{(i,j)}$) -- that's the classification part of your problem -- and you could try to use a Reccurent Neural Net (e.g. LSTM) for the prediction problem of inferring a sequence of future trip segments based on previous ones $[\boldsymbol{x}^{(i,1)}, \boldsymbol{x}^{(i,2)}, \boldsymbol{x}^{(i,3)}] \to [\boldsymbol{x}^{(i,4)}, \cdots, \boldsymbol{x}^{(i,n)}]$.

Of course there are a lot of methods and tricks out there, and choosing which ones fit best your needs is a difficult question that also depends on your goals, your dataset size, your computing ressources, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am also interested to know what other techniques can be useful to solve this problem. My goal is to do a research and perform experimentation on different data sizes and compare the results. Is their any benchmark model from which I can compare the performance of my models? can hidden markov model be helpful in this case?

Comment: What type of data is this? time series, sequence etc